# IntelliJ IDEA "file cache conflict" popup

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After every save, i get the "file cache conflict" popup in intellij.

solutions I've tried are unticking all of these

"synchronize files" (system settings)

"save files on frame deactivation"

"use safe write"

I've also tried editing the event log notification, still getting these annoying messages. 
Thank you for the help in advance!

p.s. my first post here, be gentle :D

[Logs](http://pastebin.com/Yvcbb5yY)

Comment: Do you keep the project files on the local drive? Are there any symlinks? Is that a Dropbox or Google Drive directory? What third-party plug-ins did you install? Share the [logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: Did you try these [solutions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/file-cache-conflict.html) suggested by IntelliJ?

Comment: There are no solutions there @PratikAmbani. It just explains what each button does.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes I keep the project on the local drive, but it's also in a OneDrive directory, there are no symlinks, I didn't install any plugin but the default ones. publishing the logs now.
I have IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3.4

Comment: Try moving the project folder outside of OneDrive. Its synchronization is weird and can cause such problems.